# Необычная группировка таблицы?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица

```
+--------+------------+---------------------+
| status | cashier_id | check_end           |
+--------+------------+---------------------+
|      1 |          1 | 2019-07-10 14:19:43 |
|      2 |          2 | 2019-07-09 16:19:43 |
|      3 |          1 | 2019-07-10 12:19:43 |
|      4 |          1 | 2019-07-10 11:19:43 |
+--------+------------+---------------------+
```

Как мне получить уникальные `cashier_id` как указано ниже

```
+--------+------------+---------------------+
| status | cashier_id | check_end           |
+--------+------------+---------------------+
|      1 |          1 | 2019-07-10 14:19:43 |
|      2 |          2 | 2019-07-09 16:19:43 |
+--------+------------+---------------------+
```

при условии что должна остаться строка в которой `check_end` - самое позднее из всех и `status` берется именно из этой самой поздней строки?

Comment: первичный ключ у записей есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  t.status,
  t.cashier_id,
  t.check_end
FROM
  mytable t
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      cashier_id,
      MAX(check_end) AS check_end
    FROM
      mytable t
    GROUP BY
      cashier_id
  ) sub ON (
    t.cashier_id = sub.cashier_id AND
    t.check_end = sub.check_end
  )
```

Comment: человеческое спасибо! ))